# How to only accept inputs that are 3 digit numbers?

Tags: python-2.7, while-loop

```
UserNumber = 0

UserNumber = int(raw_input("Enter a 3 digit number: "))

if UserNumber >= 100 and UserNumber <= 999:

    print "My name is: xxxxx xxxxx"
    print "My UBIT name is: xxxxxxx"
    print "The number you entered was", UserNumber, "."
```

How can I make the program only run when a 3 digit number is entered (i.e a number > 99 and number < 1000? I know it has to be some sort of while loop but I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: You can use **regex** to test it's a three digit number.  For example: \d{3} or [0-9]{3}.  If the value fails the test, have the function call itself (recursion) and re-prompt the user for the number.

Comment: what is wrong with what you have posted?

Comment: What I have posted does not check if the number is 3 digits. I’m asking to implement a fail safe to make sure that the input is a 3 digit number.

Answer (score 0):

The input is a string, therefore, you can `len(input)` before the cast to an integer.

The check that every character is a digit can be done with `and input.isdigit`.

```
UserNumber = 0

input = raw_input("Enter a 3 digit number: ")

if len(input) == 3 and input.isdigit():
    UserNumber = int(input)
    print "My name is: xxxxx xxxxx"
    print "My UBIT name is: xxxxxxx"
    print "The number you entered was", UserNumber, "."
```

But think, `007` is also a valid 3 digit number. So if you want that it is bigger than `99`, you need that check too.

---

To your "update", that you want a "fail-save" such that somebody is forced to do a 3 digits input:

```
UserNumber = 0

input = ""
while not (len(input) == 3 and input.isdigit()):
    input = raw_input("Enter a 3 digit number: ")

UserNumber = int(input)
print "My name is: xxxxx xxxxx"
print "My UBIT name is: xxxxxxx"
print "The number you entered was %03d." % UserNumber
```

As long as somebody does not input 3 digits, the question for that input will appear.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex to check if the number is 3 digits and just ask the user again if it is not matching the regex

```py
import re

UserNumber = int(raw_input("Enter a 3 digit number: "))

while not(re.search("^\d{3}$", str(UserNumber))):
    UserNumber = int(raw_input("that  was not a 3 digit number, Enter a 3 digit number: "))

if UserNumber >= 100 and UserNumber <= 999:

    print "My name is: xxxxx xxxxx"
    print "My UBIT name is: xxxxxxx"
    print "The number you entered was", UserNumber, "."
```